# Safari Extension and getJSON Wikipedia

Tags: safari

I am trying to implement a GetJSON Call to Wikipedia API from a Safari Extension, but i get always the Origin Error, if i add a callback=ß i get callback undefined Error

A simple:

```
$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=google&prop=text&format=json&callback=?', function(data) { 
    console.log(data);
});
```

Without triggering an Error would be nice, alternatively, is there another way to get a Wikipedia short summary on a keyword inside safari Extension?

thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Found a Workaround1

If you use a Globle Page or a PopOver, let it do this stuff, it doesn't trigger Orinin Errors, use than Messaging to send the Data from Global Page to the Injected Script, it works here fine